# Wayland Ubuntu 22.04 no sound output for HDMI - AMDGPU - R9 380 (Tonga)

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, hdmi, amdgpu

With the new clean `Ubuntu 22.04` install the `HDMI audio` output is not detected at all by `pulseaudio` when running display session under `Wayland` instead of `Xorg` which is now the default session for Ubuntu.

I am running the current hardware specs:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0
    Desktop: GNOME 42.2 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
    
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: N/A
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: CROSSHAIR VI HERO v: Rev 1.xx serial: <filter>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: 8503 date: 03/16/2022
    
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 1700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen
    rev: 1 cache: L1: 768 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2200 min/max: 2200/3775 boost: disabled cores: 1: 2200
    2: 2200 3: 2200 4: 2200 5: 2200 6: 2200 7: 2200 8: 2200 9: 2200 10: 2200
    11: 2200 12: 2200 13: 2200 14: 2200 15: 2200 16: 2200 bogomips: 120564
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Tonga PRO [Radeon R9 285/380] vendor: PC Partner
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus-ID: 0b:00.0
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz 3: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon R9 380 Series (tonga LLVM 13.0.1 DRM 3.42
  5.15.0-43-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.1 direct render: Yes
    
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Tonga HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 285/380] vendor: PC Partner
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 0b:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 0d:00.3
  Device-3: Plantronics Poly Blackwire 3320 Series type: USB
    driver: plantronics,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 1-10:6
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-43-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

I already had issues in the past on the same hardware with `Ubuntu 20.04` not detecting multiple connected displays. The solution for that was to add the following kernel parameters to `grub`:

```
# /etc/default/grub

# amdgpu.powerplay=0 amdgpu.dc=0 fixes multi monitor detection
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.powerplay=0 amdgpu.dc=0"
```

In addition there was crackling HDMI audio issue which was fixed by adding tsched=0 parameter here:

```
# /etc/pulse/default.pa


### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

At first I did not realize that Wayland could affect pulseaudio, so I was trying the above solutions and many other solutions found on the Internet without much luck. Once I realised that I switched back to Xorg and it started behaving like before in 20.04.

Did anyone have similar issues? Were you able to resolve them for Wayland?

Additional info:

```
$ aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=9
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=10
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 4
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=11
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 5
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=9
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=10
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 4
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HDMI,DEV=11
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 5
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=0
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=1
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=2
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=4
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=HDMI,DEV=5
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=3
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=7
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=8
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=9
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 3
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=10
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 4
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=HDMI,DEV=11
    HDA ATI HDMI, HDMI 5
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=HDMI
    HDA ATI HDMI
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=1
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC1220 Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Series
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Series,DEV=0
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Series
    Poly Blackwire 3320 Series
    USB Stream Output
```

**Update**

If I login via `xsession` and then switch to `wayland` it seems that audio outputs persist until the next reboot. Still not sure if this is `pulseaudio` or `wayland` issue.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to the problem yet? I am having the same issue

Comment: Hi @bezirganyan, unfortunately not. I switched to Xorg session for my issue until I decided to migrate to Windows due to other issues. Using Linux currently either via WSL or VM.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 22.10, 5.19.17, updating the AMD drivers solved this issue for me (as well as not waking from suspend): [enter link description here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers) I also removed the "nomodeset" from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` since the AMD setup util complains about it with KMS.